# EventBus - не выполняется метод onEvent во фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, eventbus

Доброго времени суток всем.

Из активити пытаюсь отправить данные во фрагмент при помощи библиотеки EventBus.

В методе onCreate активити добавляю фрагмент

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,
   FragmentTest.getInstance()).commit();
```

И сразу же после этого отправляю сообщение:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post("Test message");
```

Код фрагмента:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Но после этого ничего не происходит. В логах следующее:

```
No subscribers registered for event class java.lang.String
No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
```

Но если отправить сообщение следующим образом:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            EventBus.getDefault().post("Test message");
         }
      });
   }
}).start();
```

То сообщение будет успешно получено во фрагменте в методе onEvent. Что я делаю не так и почему так происходит?

Comment: Возможно, на момент того, как Вы посылаете сообщение, метод `onStart()` фрагмента еще не отработал. Во втором случае, из-за некоторой задержки, `onStart()` успевает отрабатывать.

Comment: Да, скорей всего, так оно и есть.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, на момент того, как Вы посылаете сообщение, метод `onStart()` фрагмента еще не отработал.

Во втором случае, из-за некоторой задержки, `onStart()` успевает отрабатывать.